# Given an array like [[el1,el2],[el11,el22],[el111,el222]]..... iterate and sum the second values of subarray when first value is equal

Tags: javascript

When I have an array like this

```
var test = [['11 may 2018',0],['11 may 2018',1],['12 may 2018',5],['13 may 2018',0],['14 may 2018',0],['15 may 2018',3],['15 may 2018',7],['16 may 2018',30]];
```

I want it to end up looking like this

```
var test2 = [['11 may 2018',1],['12 may 2018',5],['13 may 2018',0],['14 may 2018',0],['15 may 2018',10],['16 may 2018',30]]
```

I can't wrap my head around how to do it.

I have done something similar to this:

```
    var test = [['11 may 2018',0],['11 may 2018',1],['12 may 2018',5],['13 may 2018',0],['14 may 2018',0],['15 may 2018',3],['15 may 2018',7],['16 may 2018',30]];
var test2 = [['11 may 2018',1],['12 may 2018',5],['13 may 2018',0],['14 may 2018',0],['15 may 2018',10],['16 may 2018',30]]

var testLength = test.length;

for (let i = 0; i< testLength; i++){
    if(i != testLength -1){
        if(test[i][0] == test[i+1][0]){
            test[i][1] += test[i+1][1];
        }
    }

}
console.log(test)
```

Which returns

```
    [
  [ '11 may 2018', 1 ],
  [ '11 may 2018', 1 ],
  [ '12 may 2018', 5 ],
  [ '13 may 2018', 0 ],
  [ '14 may 2018', 0 ],
  [ '15 may 2018', 10 ],
  [ '15 may 2018', 7 ],
  [ '16 may 2018', 30 ]
]
```

Where I don't know how to delete the second instance of the repeated arrays without messing up the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for grouping same keys and get the values from the object as result.

```js
var array = [['11 may 2018', 0], ['11 may 2018', 1], ['12 may 2018', 5], ['13 may 2018', 0], ['14 may 2018', 0], ['15 may 2018', 3], ['15 may 2018', 7], ['16 may 2018', 30]],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
        r[key] = r[key] || [key, 0];
        r[key][1] += value;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just keep track of the dates in an object keyed to date and increment that as you iterate over your list. In the end the `Object.entries` of the object will be what you want:

```js
var test = [['11 may 2018',0],['11 may 2018',1],['12 may 2018',5],['13 may 2018',0],['14 may 2018',0],['15 may 2018',3],['15 may 2018',7],['16 may 2018',30]];

let counts =  test.reduce((sums, [key, count]) => {
    sums[key] = (sums[key] || 0) + count
    return sums
}, {})

console.log(Object.entries(counts))
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need a `Map` structure to tackle this kind of problem. You could do something like this:

```
const buildMap = arr => {
    const map = {};
    arr.forEach(element => {
        const [key, value] = element;
        if (map[key]) map[key] += value;
        else {
            map[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return map;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce()` on the test array to check for matching dates, and if they exist, add the integers together. Otherwise, add the new array to the accumulator.

```js
var test = [['11 may 2018',0],['11 may 2018',1],['12 may 2018',5],['13 may 2018',0],['14 may 2018',0],['15 may 2018',3],['15 may 2018',7],['16 may 2018',30]];

let res = test.reduce((acc,el) => {
   acc.forEach((accEl, idx) => {
        if(acc[idx][0] === el[0]){
            acc[idx][1] += el[1]
        }
   })
   
   if(acc.every(accEl => accEl[0] !== el[0])){
      acc.push(el)
   }
   
   return acc
}, [])

console.log(res)
```